# Select Multiple Book Titles that share the MIN(PRICE) value | MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I have found no other specific problem like this on here.

This is a single table query in MySQL.  I have a 'book' table that holds the 'title' and 'price' columns.  The problem is to find the minimum book price and display the titles with that minimum value.  My problem is that I can only return one title but there is multiple titles with that minimum value.  The title my code returns isn't even a valid one, but the first title in the table.

My current code is:

```
SELECT TITLE,
       MIN(PRICE) AS "PRICE"
FROM book;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the title(s) of the books with the lowest price with a sub query.

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM   book
WHERE  PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE)
                FROM   book);
```

The query in your question is not valid standard SQL and would be rejected by most other RDBMSs.

MySQL does not raise an error ([yet - though this is coming](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html)) but also doesn't guarantee any particular semantics of the result.

Comment: OP also wanted to view the minimum price along with the title. So shouldn't it be `SELECT TITLE, PRICE FROM book WHERE PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM book);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the minimum price in one subquery, and then find all the books whose price matches that in an outer query.

```
SELECT a.title, a.price
FROM book AS a
JOIN (SELECT MIN(price) AS minprice
      FROM book) AS b
ON a.price = b.minprice
```

Another way to write it is:

```
SELECT titla, price
FROM book 
WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM book)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a view that holds the cheapest book (minimum price):

```
CREATE VIEW minPrice AS
           (SELECT MIN(price) AS price
            FROM book)
```

Second, join your table with this view like follows:

```
SELECT book.price, book.title
FROM book
    JOIN minPrice
        ON book.price=minPrice.price
```

Comment: There is no need for a view here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it does the job

Answer (score 0):

If you are using subqueries like....

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM   book
WHERE  PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE)
            FROM   book);
```

these are little slower if are working with a large database as there are two **SELECT** statements. It will work fine though...You can also go with-:

```
SELECT title FROM book
ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1;
```